# Let $f(x) = x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 + 5x^5 + 6x^6$, and $S = [f(6)]^5 + [f(10)]^3 + [f(15)]^2$. Find the remainder when $S$ is divided by 30.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $f(x) = x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 + 5x^5 + 6x^6$, and let $S = [f(6)]^5 + [f(10)]^3 + [f(15)]^2$. Compute the remainder when $S$ is divided by 30.

I don't really know how to start this, any help is appreaciated.

Comment: A couple things jump out: you can factor an $x$ out of $f(x)$. Also, the exponents in the terms of $S$ are all prime. By Fermat's Little Theorem, $p$ divides $(a+b)^p - a^p - b^p$.

Comment: Note that $f(10)^3\equiv 0$ and $f(6)^5\equiv 6$ modulo $30$. The result is then $21$.

Comment: So far all 7 posts of you have been problem-statement questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$6^2=36 \equiv 6 \mod 30$$

$$10^2=100 \equiv 10 \mod 30$$

$$15^2=225 \equiv 15 \mod 30$$

but

$$ 6+2.6+3.6+4.6+5.6+6.6=21.6$$
thus
$$f(6)\equiv 6 \mod 30$$

You can continue. If you don't find $ 21$ as remainder, it means you made a mistake somewhere.